upgrade error: Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com' even though internet was working fine before
Whenever I try to do-release-upgrade the system first successfully connects and downloads some upgrade packages, but then at the part I added below it suddenly cannot connect to the internet anymore.
I confirm this through my browser; suddenly the internet is gone, though the wifi symbol shows full strength as if nothing is wrong. I have to reboot the machine to restore internet functionality.
What's happening here?
I suspect the update process somehow disables my internet, but how/why?
How can I fix this or upgrade anyway?
Upgrading
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'                                                                                                                                                                       
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'                                                                                                                                                                       
Fetched 0 B in 6s (39,4 MB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'                                                                                                                                                                       
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'                                                                                                                                                                       
Fetched 0 B in 6s (39,4 MB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 foomatic-filters amd64 4.0.17-16                                                                                                                     
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'                                                                                                                                                                       
Ign http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
Err http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu noble/universe amd64 python3-tomli all 2.0.1-2                                                                                                                            
  Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com'                                                                                                                                                                       
Fetched 0 B in 6s (39,4 MB/s)                                                                                                                                                                                     

Could not download the upgrades 

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or 
installation media and try again. 

Failed to fetch 
http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/f/foomatic-filters/foomatic-filters_4.0.17-16_amd64.deb 
Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com' 
Failed to fetch 
http://be.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/universe/p/python-tomli/python3-tomli_2.0.1-2_all.deb 
Could not resolve 'be.archive.ubuntu.com' 



Restoring original system state

Aborting
Reading package lists... Done    
Building dependency tree... Done 
Reading state information... Done
``


but then why can I successfully run apt-get update? and why is my internet connection down (to any website) right at the moment when the update process fails to get the packages?
I suspect the update process somehow disables my internet.
